# (Unity) Возможно ли вызвать событие/метод когда объект, на который есть ссылка в MonoBehaviour становится удалённым/утерянным?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Допустим, у нас есть вот такой класс:

```
public class Class : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Target; //Сюда уже присвоен какой-то "Transform".
}
```

*Вопрос прост:*

Возможно ли как-либо отследить и получить callback если объект "Target" будет удалён (извне)?

*Когда это происходит, в редакторе Unity обычно пишет "Missing":*
[image: 1]

Так как это Transform, здесь не прокатит использование `OnDestroy()`, и даже если это бы сработало, то имело бы проблемы с оптимизацией, учитывая сколько таких Transform-ов на сцене.

**Сразу уточню: я ищу решение, которое будет работать в билде игры - варианты, работающие только в редакторе к сожалению мне не подходят.**

Comment: если объект удалён, то переменная, обычно, имеет значение `null`

Comment: Верно, но чтобы убедиться что переменная получила такое значение нужно либо проверять это каждый кадр, либо использовать свойство, что увы не работает если объект был удалён через `Destroy(gameobject)`. Поэтому я и задал вопрос, на случай если есть более прямое решение.

Comment: Что-то не ясно. Если объект удаляется (хоть через сжатие вселенной, хоть через экспекто патронум), ссылка на него становится null. Причём тут `Destroy(gameobject)`? Можно поянсений?

Comment: Вопрос заключается в можно ли получить любого рода callback в момент **когда** этот объект становится null. Обычно, чтобы это проверить нужно выполнять логическое сравнение `Target==null`, но его нужно проводить периодически (каждый кадр, например) чтобы знать наверняка. Я задал вопрос на случай, если к этому можно привязать (или получить) какое-либо событие, которое будет вызываться однажды в момент когда ссылка становиться null. Или на случай если есть какое либо другое решение, более лаконичное чем проверка ссылки на `IsNull` каждый кадр.

Comment: Трансформ сам по себе жить не может, следовательно он прикреплен к какому-нибудь объекту. Добавьте на этот объект какой-нибудь самописный компонент, который в момент уничтожения будет вызывать какое-нибудь событие. И уже на это событие подписывайтесь в своем классе Class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Foo: MonoBehaviour
{
    public event Action Destroyed;
    
    private void OnDestroy () 
    {
        Destroyed?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class FooHandler: MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Foo _target;

    private void Start ()
    {
        _target.Destroyed += OnTargetDestroy;
    }

    private void OnTargetDestroy ()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Но ситуация какая-то странная. У вас проблемы с проектированием.

Comment: можно еще как вариант систему сигналов прикрутить и на дестрое посылать сигнал "в космос" и ловить там где это необходимо